# [python]How can make a string looks like it echoed

Tags: python

Hi one of my teachers asked me to write a program that does this

```
Type something >> House
House
oouse
uuuse
sssse
eeeee
```

as it has been echoed
(I'm new in python) I tried many ways like :

```
str = list(input())
i = 0
print(str)
for x in range(0,len(str)):
    i = 0
    for i in range(0,x):
        str[i] = str[x]
        print(str)
        i = i + 1
```

But it does not work can you help me, please.

Comment: `str` is an in-built type in Python. Be careful overwriting it in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a bit of code that should do the trick

```
try:
    input_text = list(input("Type something >> "))
    original_length = len(input_text)
    assert(len(input_text) > 1)

except:
    print("Your input word must contain more than 1 letter")
    exit()

print("\n> Saying : ", ''.join(input_text))

for _ in range(len(input_text) - 1):
    
    # --- Remove the first letter of the input word
    input_text.pop(0)
    
    # --- Filling the left part of the echo with the first letter, then adding the remaining letters
    echo = input_text[0] * (original_length - len(input_text)) + ''.join(input_text)
    print("\t> Hearing : ", echo)
```

You should see the following output :

```
> Saying :  House
        > Hearing :  oouse
        > Hearing :  uuuse
        > Hearing :  sssse
        > Hearing :  eeeee
```

Answer (score 0):

you can define how much it echos by changing the numbers 3 and 5.

```
string = 'car'
echo = string[:-2]+string[-2]*3+string[-1]*5
```

this will create 'caaarrrrr'.
if you want to print aar, followed by rrr:

```
print(string[-2]*2+string[-1])
print(string[-1]*3)
```